# How can we integrate $\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}\right)^{4}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I want to compute
$$ I_n = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi }{2}}\left(\frac{\sin nx}{\sin x}\right)^{4}\,dx.$$

How to proceed in this case? Any hint is welcome.
This question was given to me by my professor as a challenge, and I tried using all of the concepts I had known, but was unsuccessful. I tried creating a general term for $I(n)$ and $I(n-1)$ and subtracted them, but this approach failed.

Comment: For the OP: many users here tend to downvote so-called PSQs (Problem Statement Questions) like yours, and answers, too (some god will forgive them, but the poor human Jack won't). So it is in your (and community's) best interest to improve your actual question by adding some context (your attempts, why this question is relevant to you, something along these lines). Cheers.

Comment: If you want to be free of the "$\texttt{on hold}$", please read carefully $\textsf{Jack D'Aurizio}$ comment and follows his advice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$I_n$ is associated with the $L^1$-norm of the Jackson kernel.
If we start from the [Fejér kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel)
$$ F_n(x) = \sum_{|j|\leq n}\left(1-\frac{|j|}{n}\right)e^{ijx}=\frac{1}{n}\cdot\frac{\sin^2\frac{nx}{2}}{\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}\tag{1}$$
we have
$$ \frac{\sin^2(nx)}{\sin^2(x)} = n\sum_{|j|\leq n}\left(1-\frac{|j|}{n}\right)e^{2ijx}=n+2\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(n-j\right)\cos(2jx) \tag{2}$$
and $\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\cos(2jx)\cos(2kx)\,dx = \frac{\pi}{4} \delta(j,k)\tag{3} $
hence:

$$\begin{eqnarray*} \int_{0}^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^4(nx)}{\sin^4(x)}\,dx &=& \frac{\pi}{2}n^2+\pi\sum_{j=1}^{n}\left(n-j\right)^2\\\color{red}{I_n}&=&\color{red}{\frac{\pi n(2n^2+1)}{6}}.\tag{4}\end{eqnarray*} $$

Comment: This is a nice solution for sure ! Thanks for providing this answer.

Comment: Good answer although it is way out of understanding of a high schooler. Is there any other method to do it?

Comment: @ChetanPandey: is that so terrible to square both sides of $(2)$ and integrate them over $(0,\pi/2)$? We may achieve $(4)$ through Chebyshev polynomials or the Fourier transform, too. Anyway, your question is still lacking context. Where/when this problem occured to you, for instance?

Comment: Jack: I have updated the question details. Can you please elaborate how you moved from step 2-3. Thanks.

Comment: @ChetanPandey: step $(2)$ and $(3)$ are independent. Given $(2)$, we exploit the fact that $\int \cos(2jx)\cos(2kx)\,dx$ equals $\frac{\pi}{4}$ if $j=k$ and zero otherwise. So, in order to integrate $f(x)\cdot f(x)$, it is enough to apply $(3)$ (Parseval's identity), termwise, to the product between the RHS of $(2)$ and itself.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
I_{n} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\bracks{\sin\pars{nx} \over \sin\pars{x}}^{4}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}
\bracks{1 - \cos\pars{2nx} \over 1 - \cos\pars{2x}}^{2}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 4}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}
\bracks{1 - \cos\pars{nx} \over 1 - \cos\pars{x}}^{2}\,\dd =
{1 \over 4}\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}
\bracks{1 - \pars{z^{2n} + 1}/\pars{2z^{n}} \over
1 - \pars{z^{2} + 1}/\pars{2z}}^{2}\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
\\[5mm] & =
-\,{1 \over 4}\,\ic\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{2n - 1}}
\pars{2z^{n} - z^{2n} - 1 \over 2z - z^{2} - 1}^{2}\,\dd z =
-\,{1 \over 4}\,\ic\oint_{\verts{z}\ =\ 1}{1 \over z^{2n - 1}}
\pars{1 - z^{n} \over 1 - z}^{4}\,\dd z
\\[5mm] & =
{1 \over 2}\,\pi\bracks{z^{2n - 2}}\pars{1 - z^{n} \over 1 - z}^{4} =
{1 \over 2}\,\pi\braces{%
\bracks{z^{2n - 2}}\pars{1 - z}^{-4} -
4\bracks{z^{n - 2}}\pars{1 - z}^{-4}}\label{1}\tag{1}
\end{align}

---

\begin{equation}
\mbox{However,}\quad\pars{1 - z}^{-4} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{-4 \choose k}\pars{-1}^{k}z^{k} =
\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{k + 3 \choose 3}z^{k}\label{2}\tag{2}
\end{equation}

---

With \eqref{1} and \eqref{2}:
\begin{align}
I_{n} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\bracks{\sin\pars{nx} \over \sin\pars{x}}^{4}\,\dd x =
{1 \over 2}\,\pi\
\underbrace{\bracks{{2n + 1 \choose 3} - 4{n + 1 \choose 3}}}
_{\ds{n\pars{2n^{2} + 1} \over 3}}\ =\
\bbox[10px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{%
{1 \over 6}\,\pi n\pars{2n^{2} + 1}}}
\end{align}

Comment: @tired Thanks. I started it a few hours ago and i left it because I did the double expansion in (1). When I returned, I see that it was not necessary because we just need the first to terms of $\left(1 - z^{n}\right)^{4}$ which was the right clue. Otherwise it becomes rather tedious.

Comment: Oh, the residue theorem. A pretty effective choice, good work. (+1)