# Show that $\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1 - \cos nt}{1 - \cos t} \,dt = 2\pi n$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, alternative-proof

I have derived (by Fourier methods) that, for nonnegative integers $n$,
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{1 - \cos nt}{1 - \cos t} \,dt = 2\pi n.$$
I can prove this using complex analysis by the substitution $z = e^{it}$, which gives
$$ \oint_{|z|=1} \frac{(1 - z^n)(1 - z^{-n})}{(1-z)(1-z^{-1})} \frac{dz}{z} $$
to which we can apply the residue theorem, but I am interested in other proofs.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008044/how-do-i-prove-int-0-pi-frac-sin-nx2-sin-x2dx-n-pi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may look similar to the solution using the residue theorem, we use
$$
\int_0^{2\pi} \frac{(1-e^{int})(1-e^{-int})}{(1-e^{it})(1-e^{-it})}dt = \int_0^{2\pi} (1+e^{it} + \cdots + e^{i(n-1)t})(1+e^{-it}+\cdots + e^{-i(n-1)t})dt.
$$

Comment: Looking at this again, this gives a very elegant proof. Thanks!