# $I_n=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {\sin ((2n+1)x)dx}{\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

> If  $$I_n=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {\sin ((2n+1)x)dx}{\sin x}$$ then evaluate $$\lim_{n\to \infty} 2I_n$$

My try:  $$I_n=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {\sin ((2n+1)x)dx}{\sin x}$$ 
$$=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {(\sin 2nx\cos x+\cos 2nx\sin x)dx}{\sin x}$$ 
$$=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \sin (2nx)\cot (x) dx+\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \cos (2nx) dx$$

$$=\left(\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \sin (2nx)\cot (x) dx\right)+ \frac {\sin n\pi}{2n}$$

In the first integral I tried to use integration by parts and could reach up-to $$\left(\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \sin (2nx)\cot x dx\right)=\sin 2nx\ln (\sin x) -2n\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \cos 2nx\ln (\sin x) dx$$

But now I am stuck up here.  Any help would be very beneficial.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263705/compute-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin-2013x-sin-x-dx-space  and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008044/how-do-i-prove-int-0-pi-frac-sin-nx2-sin-x2dx-n-pi

Comment: @lab bhattacharjee Thanks for the links. I'll take a look at them and see if they could help. :-)

Comment: IMHO the way via the Dirichlet kernel is the easiest, as you need only to integrate some cosines and a constant and you will get nice sum.

Answer (score 2):

Apologies for this first part being rather unintuitive.

$$
\begin{aligned}
I_n-I_{n-1} &= \int_0^{\frac\pi 2} \frac{\sin(2nx+x)-\sin(2nx-x)}{\sin x}\,dx \\
&= \int_0^{\frac\pi 2} \frac{2 \cos2nx \sin x}{\sin x}\,dx \\
&=\left[\frac{\sin 2nx}{n}\right]^{\frac \pi 2}_0 = 0\,\,\mathrm{(for\, all\,} n\neq0)
\end{aligned}
$$

Therefore, $I_n = I_{n-1}$ for all $n\neq 0$.

i.e. $I_1=I_2=I_3= \,\,...$

Now, evaluating $I_1$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
I_1 &=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\frac {\sin(3x)}{\sin x}\,dx \\
&=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\frac{\sin 2x\cos x+\cos 2x\sin x}{\sin x}\,dx \\
&=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}\frac{2 \sin x\cos^2 x+\cos^2x\sin x-\sin^3x}{\sin x}
\,dx\\&=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}3 \cos^2x-\sin^2x\,dx\\
&=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}2 \cos^2x+\cos2x\,dx \\
&=\int_0^{\frac \pi 2}2 \cos 2x+1\,dx \\
&= \frac \pi 2
\end{aligned}
$$

From above, we conclude that $I_n=\frac \pi 2$ for all non-negative $n$.

Therefore, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} 2I_n = \pi$$

Comment: How did you assume that $n$ is an integer because without that you can't say that $\sin 2n\pi=0$

Comment: Huh... that’s a problem. My bad, I forgot about that. To be honest I’m not sure if the proof works without it.

Answer (score 1):

With
$\frac{a^m-a^{-m}}{ a-a^{-1}}=a^{m-1} +a^{m-3} + \dots + a^{-m+1} $
\begin{align}\int_0^\frac\pi2 \frac{\sin (2n+1)x}{\sin x} dx
 =&\int_0^\frac\pi2 \frac{e^{i(2n+1)x}-e^{-i(2n+1)x}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}} dx
=\int_0^\frac\pi2 \sum_{k=0}^{2n} e^{2i(n-k)x}dx\\
\end{align}
Note that $Re\int_0^\frac\pi2 e^{2i (n-k) x}dx =0$, except for $k=n$. Then
\begin{align}
\int_0^\frac\pi2 \frac{\sin (2n+1)x}{\sin x} dx = \int_0^\frac\pi2 1 \ dx=\frac\pi2
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

Using the substitution $u=2x$ and $du=2dx$

The integral changes to $$\frac 12\int_0^{\pi} \frac {\sin\left(\left(n+\frac 12\right)u\right)}{\sin \frac {u}{2}}du$$

And inside the integral is just the Dirichlet kernel i.e. $D_n$

Hence $$I_n=\frac 12 \left(\int_0^{\pi} 1+2\sum_{k=1}^n \cos (ku)  du\right)$$

Which simplifies to $$I_n=\frac {\pi}{2} +\sum_{k=1}^n \int_0^{\pi} \cos (ku)  du$$

The integral along with summation becomes  simply becomes $0$.

Hence $$\lim_{n\to \infty} 2I_n=\lim_{n\to \infty} 2\cdot \frac {\pi}{2}=\pi$$

Answer (score 0):

$$I_n=\int_0^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \frac {\sin ((2n+1)x)dx}{\sin x}$$

By @PKBeam, since $I_{n+1}-I_n=0$ So $I$ does not depend on $n$, so we can write
$I_n=I_0=\int_{0}^{\pi/2} dx=\pi/2$