# Compute $\int_0^\pi dx [(\sin(nx)-\sin((n-1)x))/\sin(x/2)]^2$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

Is is possible to evaluate analytically the integral

$\int_0^\pi dx \left[\frac{\sin(nx)-\sin((n-1)x)}{\sin(x/2)}\right]^2$

where $n\in\mathbb N$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this a homework problem? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Yes, it is possible.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008044/how-do-i-prove-int-0-pi-frac-sin-nx2-sin-x2dx-n-pi

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Use the formula
$$\sin a-\sin b=2\cos\left(\frac{a+b}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{a-b}{2}\right)$$