# Prove $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{dk}{2 \pi} \frac{\cos(nk)-1}{\cos(k)-1} = n$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

The following integral comes up in the theory of Brownian motion in 1D:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{dk}{2 \pi} \frac{\cos(nk)-1}{\cos(k)-1} = n$$
where $n \in \mathbf{N}$. Does anybody know a short proof of this formula?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2008044/how-do-i-prove-int-0-pi-frac-sin-nx2-sin-x2dx-n-pi
   and 
 https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263705/compute-int-0-pi-2-frac-sin-2013x-sin-x-dx-space

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $$I_n = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{ \cos(nk) - 1}{\cos k - 1} \,dk.$$

Then
$$
\begin{align*}
\frac{I_{n+1} + I_{n-1}}{2} &= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{-2 + \cos(n+1)k + \cos(n-1)k}{2( \cos k -1)} \,dk \\
&= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{-1+ \cos nk \cos k}{\cos k - 1} \,dk \\
&= \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{(\cos nk -1) + \cos nk(\cos k-1)}{ \cos k -1} \,dk \\
&= I_n + \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \cos nk \,dk \\
&= I_n
\end{align*}
$$
Thus, $$I_n = \frac{1}{2} (I_{n+1} + I_{n-1})$$ and this is an arithmetic sequence.

One checks that $I_0 = 0$ and $I_1 = 2 \pi$ so dividing by $2\pi$ yields the result you wanted.

Comment: Nice solution! (+1)

Answer (score 2):

Let $z=e^{ik}$ and then
$$ \cos k=\frac12(z+\frac1z), \cos nk=\frac12(z^n+\frac1{z^n}). $$
So
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \frac{dk}{2 \pi} \frac{\cos(nk)-1}{\cos(k)-1}&=&\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{\frac12(z^n+\frac1{z^n})-1}{\frac12(z+\frac1z)-1}\frac{dz}{iz}\\
&=&\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{(1-z^n)^2}{z^n(1-z)^2}dz\\
&=&\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^n}(\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}z^{k})^2\\
&=&\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1}\frac{1}{z^n}(\cdots+nz^{n-1}+\cdots)dz\\
&=&\frac{1}{2\pi i}2\pi i n=n.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: (+1) for exploiting contour integration.

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:** It is a nice exercise to show that it holds
$$\frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{1 - \cos(nx)}{1 - \cos x}\right)  = \frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{\sin \frac{n x}{2}}{\sin \frac{x}{2}}\right)^2 = \sum_{|j|\le n-1}\left(1-\frac{|j|}{n}\right)e^{ijx}$$
for every $n\in \mathbf N$. Now use the third expression to calculate your integral. By the way, the function $x\mapsto  \frac{1}{n} \left(\frac{1 - \cos(nx)}{1 - \cos x}\right)$ is called the [Fejer kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r_kernel).